# get htaccess to ignore part of a Url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a file called car-details.php it takes the variable id= with the cars registration details in order to populate the page.

I can currently get this rewrite rule working

```
RewriteRule ^car-for-sale/(.*) car-details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

But I would like to have a url like

```
/GV09LBX/Ford-car-something-etc
```

but for some reason I just can't get the second part of the url to work. I followed some guides in order to add a second part to the url example below

```
RewriteRule ^car-for-sale/(.*)/(.*) car-details.php?id=$1&something=$2 [NC,L]
```

Where something=$2 isn't even used by the car-details.php file but I would just like to have the car name in the url for seo purposes. Whenever I've tried to add a second forward slash the rewrite rule stops working. Any help?

full htaccess file below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^car-for-sale/(.*)/(.*) car-details.php?id=$1&something=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress



# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/shipley/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use anchor in your patterns:

```
RewriteRule ^car-for-sale/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ car-details.php?id=$1&something=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^car-for-sale/([^/]+)/?$ car-details.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Copied and pasted that where the old rule used to be.

The /car-for-sale/GV09LBX               works

but /car-for-sale/GV09LBX/randomText       still returns to the home page

Comment: I have tested these 2 rules on my Apache and both `/car-for-sale/GV09LBX/randomText` and `/car-for-sale/GV09LBX` are working fine with these rules.

Comment: I ended up getting this one to work, for some reason I had to get rid of the /car-for-sale/ part

RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9]*)/([^/]*)$ /car-details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]

I'll mark you as answered me because you were the only one to help. Thank you anyway :)